# Magento - Can I send packing slip as email when order is placed and send together with order mail

Tags: php, email, magento

when an order is placed the client receives an email and the order department gets a copy. The department would also like to be sent a packing slip as email straight away instead of having to print a pdf.
So apart form the fact that I'd have to make an HTML template for the packing slip, how could I get Magento to send an other email AND use an other template?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer and then have it fire the code you require

Comment: I'm afraid I'm fairly new to programming Magento - do you perhaps have tutorial suggestions for a case like this??

Comment: Could you direct me to file that selects and sends the HTML template?

Comment: hi try http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before and for a list of the observers try https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/